# What's the difference between returning value or Promise.resolve from then()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

What is the difference between:

```js
new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    res("aaa");
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    return "bbb"; // directly returning string
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

and this:

```js
new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    res("aaa");
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    return Promise.resolve("bbb"); // returning a promise
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

I'm asking as I'm getting different behaviour Using Angular and $http service with chaining .then(). A bit too much code hence first the example above.

Comment: What "different behavior" are you seeing? Both examples should work and behave approximately the same. The `Promise.resolve()` in the second example is unnecessary.

Comment: @pixelbits There is nothing wrong whatsoever with returning a promise from a `then` handler, in fact, it's a key aspect of the promises spec that you can do that.

Comment: Note that this works with arbitrarily nested `then`s - the 'other languages' term for this is that `then` is both a `map` and a `flatMap`.

Comment: in line 2 why do you have to call res("aaa"), why can't return "aaa" be sufficient and the Promise catch for resolve() it in the same way that it catches exceptions for reject() ?

Comment: @SamLiddicott having the same question, while mines are a bit more complicate: `new Promise((res, rej) => { return fetch('//google.com').then(() => { return "haha"; })  }).then((result) => alert(result));` This code will just hang (not resolved forever). But if I change `return "haha";` to `return res("haha");` then it'll work and alert "haha". Didn't the fetch().then() already wrap "haha" into a resolved promise?

Comment: @ShaungCheng if you use the Promise constructor, you should call the `res` parameter of the function passed instead of returning the result. Returning anything inside of the function passed to the Promise constructor will be ignored

Answer (score 203):

In simple terms, inside a `then` handler function:

**A) When `x` is a value (number, string, etc):**

1. `return x` is equivalent to `return Promise.resolve(x)`
2. `throw x` is equivalent to `return Promise.reject(x)`

**B) When `x` is a Promise that is already settled (not pending anymore):**

1. `return x` is equivalent to `return Promise.resolve(x)`, if the Promise was already resolved.
2. `return x` is equivalent to `return Promise.reject(x)`, if the Promise was already rejected.

**C) When `x` is a Promise that is pending:**

1. `return x` will return a pending Promise, and it will be evaluated on the subsequent `then`.

Read more on this topic on the [Promise.prototype.then() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).

Comment: 【B) 2.】should be "throw x" ?

Comment: @Lancer.Yan Not really, what B is indicating is that the behavior of `return` changes depending on the settled value of the Promise. When writing the code you don't really know if it will resolve or reject. Of course, you can have a try-catch to handle rejects and then re-throw, but that's a different scenario.

Comment: This is the best summary of the spec I've seen.

Answer (score 154):

The rule is, if the function that is in the `then` handler returns a value, the promise resolves/rejects with that value, and if the function returns a promise, what happens is, the next `then` clause will be the `then` clause of *the promise the function returned*, so, in this case, the first example falls through the normal sequence of the `thens` and prints out values as one might expect, in the second example, the promise object that gets returned when you do `Promise.resolve("bbb")`'s then is the `then` that gets invoked when chaining(for all intents and purposes). The way it actually works is described below in more detail.

Quoting from the Promises/A+ spec:

> The promise resolution procedure is an abstract operation taking as input a promise and a value, which we denote as `[[Resolve]](promise, x)`. **If `x` is a thenable, it attempts to make promise *adopt the state of `x`*, under the assumption that x behaves at least somewhat like a promise**. Otherwise, it fulfills promise with the value `x`.
>
> This treatment of thenables allows promise implementations to interoperate, as long as they expose a Promises/A+-compliant then method. It also allows Promises/A+ implementations to “assimilate” nonconformant implementations with reasonable then methods.

The key thing to notice here is this line:

> if `x` is a promise, **adopt its state** [3.4]
>
> link: https://promisesaplus.com/#point-49

Comment: "Adopt its state" is a concise and useful way to express the behavior when a `then` handler returns a promise. +1 for the spec reference.

Comment: Actually - the relevant part of the spec here is the fact that `[[Resolve]]` is called both on `then`ables and values so essentially it wraps a value with the promise so `return "aaa"` is the same as `return Promise.resolve("aaa")` and `return Promise.resolve("aaa")` is the same as `return Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve("aaa"))` - since resolve is idempotent calling it on a value more than once has the same result.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum does it mean that return `"aaa"` and `return Promise.resolve("aaa")` are interchangeable in `then`ables in any cases?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: "if the function that is in the then handler returns a value, the promise resolves/rejects with that value," I think the answer should clarify when the promise resolves and when it rejects instead of saying "the promise resolves/rejects".

Answer (score 105):

Both of your examples should behave pretty much the same.

A value returned inside a `then()` handler becomes the resolution value of the promise returned from that `then()`. If the value returned inside the `.then`  is a promise, the promise returned by `then()` will "adopt the state" of that promise and resolve/reject just as the returned promise does.

In your first example, you return `"bbb"` in the first `then()` handler, so `"bbb"` is passed into the next `then()` handler.

In your second example, you return a promise that is immediately resolved with the value `"bbb"`, so `"bbb"` is passed into the next `then()` handler. (The `Promise.resolve()` here is extraneous).

The outcome is the same.

If you can show us an example that actually exhibits different behavior, we can tell you why that is happening.

Comment: Nice answer! What about `Promise.resolve();` vs `return;`?

Comment: @FabianTe Those also would have the same effect, except with `undefined` instead of `"bbb"`.

Answer (score 54):

You already got a good formal answer. I figured I should add a short one.

The following things are identical with [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) promises:

- Calling `Promise.resolve` (In your Angular case that's `$q.when`)
- Calling the promise constructor and resolving in its resolver. In your case that's `new $q`.
- Returning a value from a `then` callback.
- Calling Promise.all on an array with a value and then extract that value.

So the following are all identical for a promise or plain value X:

```
Promise.resolve(x);
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ resolve(x); });
Promise.resolve().then(function(){ return x; });
Promise.all([x]).then(function(arr){ return arr[0]; });
```

And it's no surprise, the promises specification is based on the [Promise Resolution Procedure](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-45) which enables easy interoperation between libraries (like $q and native promises) and makes your life overall easier. Whenever a promise resolution might occur a resolution occurs creating overall consistency.

Comment: may I ask what's the point in doing `Promise.resolve().then(function(){ return x; });`?

I found a snipped doing something similar (it called a function inside the `then` block). I thought it was more or less like doing a timeout, but it's a bit faster.
http://jsben.ch/HIfDo

Comment: There is no point it's the same as Promise.resolve(x) in 99.99% of cases. (the 0.001% is that we are in a `with` block over an object or proxy with an `x` property accessor that throws an exception. In that case Promise.resolve(x) would cause a thrown error but `Promise.resolve().then(function(){ return x; });` would be a rejected promise since the error is thrown in a `then`).

Comment: you linked an empty blitz, or you didn't save.
Anyway I wasn't talking about the differences among statements. I was talking precisely about what I wrote.
Just to be more clear, this is the snippet I was talking about:
`if (validator) {
                Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                    this._cdRef.markForCheck();
                });
            }`. Here the promise isn't assigned, so what's the point? A timeout would have (more or less) the same effect, or not?

Comment: It performs the call asynchronously after all synchronous code has happened but before any I/O happens. That's called "microtick semantics".

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that you're creating an unnecessary promise when you do `return Promise.resolve("bbb")`. Returning a promise from an `onFulfilled()` handler kicks off [promise resolution](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/promise-resolve). That's how [promise chaining](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/then#chaining) works.

Answer (score 0):

Just a point. The 'resolve' function does not return as you can see in a debugger. It seems to return if it is the last statement. 'Resolve' will set the promise as fullfilled but continue execution if there are more statements below.

As you can read here:  ['Why does javascript ES6 Promises continue execution after a resolve?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66816426/2088350)

This was very confusing for me because it is not explained in most examples. So from now on, I have to remember to use 'return resolve(value)' or an 'if resolve(value) else ...other code' or just use 'resolve' as the last statement.