# How to stop promise chain after resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to stop promise chain after it resolved via some conditions. Below code is might useful to understand what am I saying.

```
function update(id, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let conn;

        pool.get()
        .then((db) => {
            conn = db;

            if(Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
                return resolve({ updated: 0 });
            }
            else {
                return generateHash(data.password);
            }
        })
        .then((hash) => {
            conn.query("UPDATE ... ", (err, queryResult) => {
                if(err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                resolve({ updated: queryResult.affectedRows });
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => { ... })
    });
}
```

Note that pool.get() is promise wrapped API for getting connection pool from MySQL module that I made.

What I'm trying to do is updating user data. And for save server resources, I avoided to update if no data to update(Object.keys(data).length === 0).

When I tried this code, second then(updating db) is always happening even if no data to update!

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896280/why-does-javascript-es6-promises-continue-execution-after-a-resolve), but it didn't worked. Why the promise chain wasn't stopped when I called "return resolve();"? And how to I stop it properly? I  really like using Promises, but sometimes, this kind of things make me crazy. It will be very appreciate to help me this problem. Thanks!

P.S. I'm using node v6.2.2 anyway.

Comment: firstly, you're using the Promise constructor antipattern ... secondly, resolving in one part of the chain guarantees to fall through to the next .then - that's how promise chains work!

Comment: You can take help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714460/break-promise-chain-and-call-a-function-based-on-the-step-in-the-chain-where-it

Comment: Why would you wait until **after** you `pool.get` before checking if the incoming `data` has no keys?

Comment: @torazaburo - that would be the value of `hash` in the next `.then` callback

Comment: though ... `hash` doesn't seem to be used at all

Comment: First of all, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi - going to need a Promise constructor eventually in that code :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, but not in that place :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why the promise chain wasn't stopped when I called "return resolve();"?

You've returned from the current `then` callback and fulfilled the outer promise. But that doesn't "stop" anything, then `then` chain still will continue by resolving with the return value of the callback.

> And how to I stop it properly?

You need to [put the `then` call inside the `if`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29500221/1048572) to have the condition apply to it:

```
pool.get()
.then((db) => {
    …
    if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
        …({ updated: 0 });
    } else {
        return generateHash(data.password)
        .then((hash) => {
            conn.query("UPDATE ... ", (err, queryResult) => {
                …
            });
        })
    }
})
.catch((err) => { ... })
```

And in any case, you should avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! You should only [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) the `query` method:

```
function query(conn, cmd) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conn.query(cmd, (err, queryResult) => {
            if (err) reject(err); // Don't throw!
            else resolve(queryResult);
        });
    });
}
```

and then use that:

```
function update(id, data) {
    return pool.get()
    .then(conn => {
        if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
            conn.close(); // ???
            return { updated: 0 };
        } else {
            return generateHash(data.password)
            .then(hash => {
                return query(conn, "UPDATE ... ")
            }).then(queryResult => {
                conn.close(); // ???
                return { updated: queryResult.affectedRows };
            }, err => {
                …
                conn.close(); // ???
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Notice that it might not make sense to get a connection from the pool if you can know beforehand that no query will be made, so probably you should put the `if` on the top level:

```
function update(id, data) {
   if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
       return Promise.resolve({ updated: 0 });
    } else {
       return pool.get()
       .then(conn => {
            return generateHash(data.password)
            .then(hash => {
                return query(conn, "UPDATE ... ")
            }).then(queryResult => {
                conn.close(); // ???
                return { updated: queryResult.affectedRows };
            }, err => {
                …
                conn.close(); // ???
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm `return resolve({ updated: 0 });` ... Promise.resolve perhaps?

Comment: @JaromandaX Dunno, that's the non-cleaned-up version where I only focused on the `if`/`then` nesting

Comment: you missed the => in `conn.query(cmd, (err, queryResult) => {`

Comment: there's a stray `;` after `return generateHash(data.password)` - ... and this also assumes that `generateHash` returns a promise, doesn't it?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, that's the assumption - otherwise OP wouldn't have to use a `then` chain with it, would he? Btw, feel free to fix any typos with edits directly

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good situation to use an `if` statement:

```
function update(id, data) {
    if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
        return Promise.resolve({ updated: 0 }); 
    }

    let conn;

    return pool.get()
        .then((db) => {
            conn = db;

            return generateHash(data.password);
        })
        .then((hash) => {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                conn.query("UPDATE ... ", (err, queryResult) => {
                    if(err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }

                    resolve({ updated: queryResult.affectedRows });
                });
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => { ... })
}
```

Comment: replace `$q.when` with `Promise.resolve` and `$q(...` with `new Promise(...` - because there's no indication that this `$q` library is being used in the question

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you. For some reason I thought it was an Angular question.