# Stop Axios Promise Chain

Tags: javascript, axios

What's the right way to break out of this chain? Like, if I'm in the catch, I don't want the following two `then`s to execute.

I used to have the `catch` last, but moved it up, thinking it might help. It didn't.

```
return axios
  .post(url, data)
  .catch(error => {
    const message = getBannerTextFailureMessage(liability, toStatus)
    dispatch(showBanner(message, bannerConstants.typeError))
  })
  .then(response => {
    return dispatch(updateLiabilitiesComplete())
  })
  .then(response => {
    const message = getBannerTextSuccessMessage(liability, toStatus)
    dispatch(showBanner(message, bannerConstants.typeSuccess))
  })
```

Comment: possible duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955607/how-to-stop-promise-chain-after-resolve)

Comment: Any reason for tagging with [tag:c#]?

Comment: Nope. Mistake. It's gone now.

Comment: It does not make any sense unless you return something from catch..

Answer (score 1):

`.catch` catches any previous parts of the promise chain and leaves following `.then`s without reject function after `.catch` uncatched (unless there is another `.catch`). It means that your chain is failing probably in one of `.then` when `.catch` is in the end of chain and probably throws promise error into console when you left it uncatched (`.catch` immediately after `.post`).

Just remove(temporary) `.catch` and find out in which part it fails - from console log.

Answer (score 0):

After resolving the promise `catch` is used to catch any error from any of the `then` block. So if you put a `catch` block after `then`, the first error from the which may occur from the previous `then` blocks will be caught. So using catch where you have used makes no sense, also the first `then` block gets the return value from the promise after being resolved.

In the catch block:

do `console.log(error)` to find out what error you get.

Also to retrieve the values from a Promise resolved functions use `eventlisteners`(to break the chaining).