# Is there a difference between `resolve` then `return` and `return resolve()`

Tags: javascript

I know about code after resolve will be executed; I'm not talking about that.
My question is about returning a `resolve` object like:

```js
return resolve(err)
```

Is it different from returning nothing? Like:

```js
resolve(err)
return
```

which is like

```js
  ...
  resolve(err)
}
```

I'm talking about the canonical case where the promise is handled with then and catch like:

```js
functionReturningAPromise().then().catch()
```

Comment: It happened to me to write code like that, and I did it just to use one line in place of two. It can be useful when you don't want to use brackets for if, like: `if (err) return resolve(err);`.

Comment: I do that as well, and sometimes both. until now it popped to my eyes, but still not convinced with @jabaa answer. See my comment

Comment: There is actually discussion of your question in the comments in this duplicate [Why does javascript ES6 Promises continue execution after a resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896280/why-does-javascript-es6-promises-continue-execution-after-a-resolve)

Comment: that is not the same ! I know code continues execution. (ah in comments, right right)

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
return resolve(err);
```

doesn't make much sense and could be confusing. `resolve` doesn't explicitly return anything. The only reason to use

```
return resolve(err);
```

is to shorten

```
resolve(err);
return;
```

That means that

```
return resolve(err);
```

and

```
resolve(err); 
return;
```

are equivalent.

Comment: well from JavaScript perspective, they are not the same, one is returning "something," the other is returning nothing. I know this whole implementation is wrapped in what we call a Promise. So now the question are Promises implemented to ignore what we return ? I hope you see what I'm referring to. THEY ARE NOT THE SAME from JS perspective.

Comment: @Curcuma_ Both return the same `undefined`. A return statement without return value returns `undefined`. `resolve` implicitly returns `undefined` and `return resolve(err)` explicitly returns `undefined`. Same result. No difference.

Comment: Arguably they return different `undefined`s ;)

Comment: you cannot return two times inside one block. @jabaa you are too convinced but wrong. `resolve` does not `return`

Comment: @Curcuma_ You can be sure I would already have gotten the first downvote, if both weren't equivalent. `resolve` doesn't return from the function. It **is** a function with a return value. `resolve` implicitly returns `undefined`. Try `console.log(resolve(err));`

Comment: Did i say they were magic? I was merely making the semantic observation that the first returns the return value of `resolve()` (which is undefined) while the second returns it's own undefined. (regardless of the fact that they are indistinguishable from each other, thus the wink)

Comment: @Curcuma_ In addition, the returned value is discarded. `resolve(err); return 123;` has the same behavior. You can't access the value `123`. More details about the promise executer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise

Comment: @jabaa I understand that. Still 123 is returned but could not be exploited (value or pointer if object is lost because of the implementation of promises).

Comment: Your answer is correct but @pilchard who proved why. thnx :)