# Why does the Promise constructor require a function that calls 'resolve' when complete, but 'then' does not - it returns a value instead?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

As I plunge into studying `Promise`s, my understanding has halted on the following question that I do not find discussed (all I find are specific discussions of the `Promise` constructor, and the `Promise` '`then`' function - but not a discussion that compares their design patterns).

---

**1. The `Promise` constructor**

[From the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), **we have this use of the Promise constructor** (with my comment added):

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { ... }); // <-- Call this Stage 1
```

> Function object with two arguments `resolve` and `reject`. The first
> argument fulfills the promise, the second argument rejects it. We can
> call these functions, once our operation is completed.

---

**2. The `then` function**

**Moving on to the `then` function** that can be called on a `Promise` object (which returns a new `Promise` object), we have [the following function signature as described by the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) (with my comments added):

```
p.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
```

> **Chaining**
>
> Because the `then` method returns a Promise, you can easily chain then
> calls.

```
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(1); // <-- Stage 1 again
});

p2.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // 1
  return value + 1; // <-- Call this Stage 2
}).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // 2
});
```

---

**My question**

From the above code snippet, it seems clear to me that the **value passed to the `resolve` function in Stage 1** (in the second occurrence of `resolve` - beneath (2), above) is passed on to the next stage (the first `then` function that follows in the same code snippet).  **There is no return value at Stage 1.**  However, it is the *return value* at Stage 2 that is passed on to the next stage after that (the second `then` function).

Is this lack of correspondence between the design pattern for the creation of a `Promise`, and the use of the `then` function on an existing promise (which also returns a `Promise`), just a historical fluke (one requires calling a callback but returns nothing, and the other returns a value but does not call a callback)?

Or am I missing an underlying reason why the `Promise` constructor utilizes a different design pattern than the `then` function?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. It has bugged me too: The Promise constructor and the `then` method seem similar... how do they compare and contrast?

Comment: Thanks for asking this, it's such a fundamental concept, it shouldn't require ANY mental gymnastics to comprehend

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324439/423105) is excellent, and has been very helpful to me. This answer is complementary to his. In order to visualize the relationship between the `Promise()` constructor and the `then()` method, I created this diagram. I hope it helps somebody... maybe even me, a few months months from now.

The main idea here is that the "executor" function passed to the `Promise()` constructor sets tasks in motion that will **set the state** of the promise; whereas the handlers you pass to `then()` will **react to the state** of the promise.

[image: Diagram: Promise() executor vs. then() method]
(Code examples adapted from [Jake Archibald's classic tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises#promisifying_xmlhttprequest).)

This is a highly simplified view of how things work, leaving out many important details. But I think if one can keep a grip on a good overview of the intended purpose, it will help avoid confusion when one gets into the details.

## A couple of selected details

### The executor is called immediately

One important detail is that the executor function passed to the `Promise()` constructor is called **immediately** (before the constructor returns the promise); whereas the handler functions passed to the `then()` method will not be called till **later** (if ever).

Bergi mentioned this, but I wanted to restate it without using the terms a/synchronously, which can be confused if you're not reading carefully: The distinction between a function *calling* something asynchronously vs. *being called* asynchronously is easy to gloss over in communication.

### `resolve()` is not `onFulfill()`

One more detail I'd like to emphasize, because it confused me for a while, is that the `resolve()` and `reject()` callbacks passed to the `Promise()` constructor's executor function **are not** the callbacks later passed to the `then()` method. This seems obvious in retrospect, but the apparent connection had me spinning in circles for too long. There is definitely a connection, but it's a loose, dynamic one.

Instead, the `resolve()` and `reject()` callbacks are functions **supplied by the "system"**, and are passed to the executor function by the `Promise` constructor when you create a promise. When the `resolve()` function is called, system code is executed that potentially changes the state of the promise and eventually leads to an `onFulfilled()` callback being called asynchronously. Don't think of calling `resolve()` as being a tight wrapper for calling `onFulfill()`!

Comment: Great question @DanNissenbaum and super helpful answer Lars. Your last paragraph cleared up a massive headache for me. Thank you.

Comment: @LarsH: I want more of this! Could you please point me to where can I read about how promises work internally, especially when dressed as async/await?
I have a problem: I can't feel at ease with something if I don't understand it in full. I've read a gazillion blog posts and still cannot rest. You seem to have gotten the gist of it; thanks for generously sharing!

Comment: @Juan: I understand the desire to really grasp something before using it -- often it prevents a lot of time-consuming messes. However I don't think I have more to offer you. I was trying to get my mind around promises when I wrote this answer, but I ended up not using them much, and now I've forgotten some of what I had learned. I guess if you want to understand promises well, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises is a pretty good source to read. I don't know anything about async/await.

Comment: @LarsH: Thanks Lars. I've already read the MDN docs and didn't got satisfaction. I keep reading and programming, and eventually I might be able to master it all. Thanks again!

Comment: `Don't think of calling resolve() as being a tight wrapper for calling onFulfill()!` This helped me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 32):

There is no correspondence between the `Promise` constructor and the `then` method because they are two independent things, designed for different purposes.

The `Promise` constructor is only used for [promisifying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)<sup>1</sup> asynchronous functions. Indeed, as you say, it is built on *invoking* `resolve`/`reject` callbacks to *asynchronously send* values, and there are no return values in that case.

That the `Promise` constructor itself does take this "resolver" callback (to which it synchronously passes `resolve` and `reject`) is in fact an enhancement of the older *deferred pattern*, and bears **no intended similarity** to the `then` callbacks.

```
var p = new Promise(function(res, rej) {    |    var def = Promise.Deferred();
    setTimeout(res, 100);                   |    setTimeout(def.resolve, 100);
});                                         |    var p = def.promise;
```

The `then` callbacks in contrast are classical asynchronous callbacks, with the [additional feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) that you can `return` from them. They are *being invoked asynchronously* to *receive* values.

```
p.then(function(val) { … });
```

To sum up the differences:

- `Promise` is a constructor, while `then` is a method
- `Promise` takes one callback, while `then` takes up to two
- `Promise` invokes its callback synchronously, while `then` invokes its callbacks asynchronously
- `Promise` always invokes its callback,
  `then` might not invoke its callbacks (if the promise is not fulfilled/rejected)
- `Promise` passes the capabilities to resolve/reject a promise to the callback,
  `then` passes the result value / rejection reason of the promise it was called on
- `Promise` invokes its callback for the purpose of executing side effects (call `reject`/`resolve`),
  `then` invokes its callbacks for their result values (for chaining)

Yes, both do return promises, though they share that trait with many other functions (`Promise.resolve`, `Promise.reject`, `fetch`, …). In fact all of these are based on the same promise construction and resolve/reject capabilities that also the `Promise` constructor provides, though that's not their primary purpose. `then` basically offers the ability to attach `onFulfilled`/`onRejected` callbacks to an existing promise, which is rather diametral to the `Promise` constructor.

That both utilise callbacks is just coincidential - not a historical fluke, but rather coadaption of a language feature.

<sub>1: Ideally, you would never need this because all natively asynchronous APIs return promises</sub>

Comment: I thought that the `then` function is also passed an asynchronous function - i.e., a function that executes asynchronously, just as the function passed to the `Promise` constructor executes asynchronously?

Comment: From your edited post, it seems to me that the answer to my question could be, fairly, that the reason for the different design is a historical fluke.  As it currently stands, the `Promise` constructor and the `then` function seem to me to be analogous in purpose - both being passed a function that is to execute asynchronously, both returning a new `Promise` object, and both passing a value along to the next stage (i.e., the next `Promise` object in the chain).  Though the explanation for the historical fluke (if that is a fair statement) that you've given is very informative.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: No, if `then` takes a (or two) callback functions that are themselves asynchronous, then those need to *return* promises.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: No, they are absolutely not analogous. The `Promise` constructor is used to create a promise from nothing, the `then` method is used to get the value from an existing promise.

Comment: Your comment that the `then` callbacks must return a `Promise` in order to execute a function that runs asynchronously answers my question - in fact, it seems that when you call `then`, the function executes **synchronously** (whereas the function passed to the `Promise` constructor executes **asynchronously**).  Be nice if that were clear from the documentation I linked in my question!  This answers my question.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: This StackOverflow answer makes it very clear that you must return a `Promise` from the `then` function in order to support asynchronous behavior for the chained `then` functions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27716590/368896

Comment: @Dan About a year later is a good time to accept this excellent response.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: I wonder whether this discussion was stumbling over wording. When Bergi says the `then` callbacks are *"invoked asynchronously"*, that pretty clearly means those callbacks are not called immediately (when `then()` executes) but 'later.' But when you say "the function passed to the `Promise` constructor executes *asynchronously*", you hopefully don't mean the same thing, because that ('executor') function executes immediately. Maybe you mean the executor function typically starts asynchronous tasks, which call `resolve` or `reject` later?

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  I switched to accept LarsH's answer because it was an excellent answer that appeared more than a year later.

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by the previous answers (I'll address the part that was most confusing to me):

The `resolve` and `reject` arguments in the Promise constructor are not functions you define. Think of them as hooks that you get to embed into your async operation code (usually you `resolve` with success response and `reject` with failure reason) , so that javascript has a way to eventually mark the Promise as Fulfilled or Rejected depending on the outcome of your async operation; once that happens, the appropriate function you defined in `then(fun1, fun2)` is triggered to consume the Promise (either `fun1(success_response)` or `fun2(failure_reason)`, depending on whether the Promise is Fulfilled/Rejected). Since `fun1` and `fun2` are plain old javascript functions (they just happen to take the future outcome of your async operation as arguments), they `return` values (which can be `undefined` if you don't explicitly return).

Also see great articles by Mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I spent hours trying to understand where the mysterious "functions" resolve and reject were defined...Nobody explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of the promise constructor executor function is to disseminate resolve and reject functions to non-promise-using code, to wrap it and convert it to use a promise. If you wanted to limit this to synchronous functions only, then yes, a return value from the function could have been used instead, but that would have been silly since the useful part is to disseminate the resolver and reject functions to code that actually runs later (way after the return), e.g. to callbacks passed in to some asynchronous API.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the execution flow of Promise.

```js
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
console.log("1");
resolve("OK");
});


//The above code creates a promise and execustion starts immediately.
//it happens aynchronously. So the execution will not be blocked. 
//Promise exustion will not wait for 'then' call on promise

console.log("2");
//The above line displays 2 on the console. 

p.then((result)=>{
console.log("3");
console.log(result);
});

//The above code shoud not block execution. So it may print 4 first 
// then 3
console.log("4");
```