# Why does return not resolve in this case?

Tags: javascript, promise

This will log 5 and 1:

```js
console.log(5)
    var promise1 = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{resolve(1)});
    promise1.then(info=>{console.log(info)});
```

This will log 5 only:

```js
console.log(5)
    var promise1 = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{return 1});
    promise1.then(info=>{console.log(info)});
```

Why doesn't the first case log 1? I thought returning a value to the promise was same as returning value to it?

Comment: Because `return` does no resolve promises. If promises would be resolved with the return value, they could not be resolved asynchronously.

Comment: You might be [confusing this with the behavior of `then`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31324110/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi yup, that's why i was confused thanks :)