# Why is `.catch` callback not triggered

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code that uses native promises:

```
function getUser() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        reject();
    });
}

function changeUser() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return getUser().catch(function (responseData, test) {
            console.log('boo error'); // this logs `boo error`
            throw {};
        });
    });
}

changeUser().then(function () {
    console.log('done');
}).catch(function () {
    console.log('error'); // this is not triggered
});
```

When I run it, the lst `catch` block with `console.log('error');` is not executed. Why is that? Is the implementation of native promises different from `Q`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw take a look at this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you never `reject` the promise you return from `changeUser`. You're only `throw`ing within the chain of the promise returned from `getUser`, which cascades within that chain, but doesn't influence the `new Promise` constructed in `changeUser`.

Either:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return getUser().then(resolve, function (responseData, test) {
        console.log('boo error'); // this logs `boo error`
        reject();
    });
});
```

Or:

```
function changeUser() {
    return getUser().catch(function (responseData, test) {
        console.log('boo error'); // this logs `boo error`
        throw {};
    });
}
```

Comment: but isn't the promise returned by `getUser().then(` becomes the promise returned by `new Promise` as happens using `Q` library?

Comment: Nope, the ECMAScript standard Promise implementation does not specify for the executor to be able to return anything. You can "renew the chain" within a `then`, not within the constructor. http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-executor

Comment: thanks, so the behavior [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27716590/2545680) talks about _the next then clause will be the then clause of the promise the function returned,_ is not applicable to executors, only to `then` methods?

Comment: It pretty explicitly talks about what's going on in the `.then` handler, yes.

Comment: thanks, so there is no way to chain/merge two promise constructors without using `resolve` or `reject` callbacks?

Comment: Mostly it doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If all you're doing from the executor is to return a different promise, why are you instantiating a `new Promise` to begin with…?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're nesting two different promise chains in the `changeUser` function. The `resolve` and `reject` functions are never called in that function, thus the `throw {}` does not bubble up. If you execute this in Chrome you'll also get a 'Uncaught promise' message in the console.

Either fix it by:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    return getUser().catch(function (responseData, test) {
        console.log('boo error'); // this logs `boo error`
        throw {};
    }).then(resolve, reject);
});
```

Or by removing the `return new Promise` line altogether.

Comment: Removing the `return new Promise` is the better solution, imo