# JavaScript Promises: chaining promises with non-promise objects. Why it works?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm learning about [JavaScript Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and I'm a bit confusing about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Consider this dummy example that prints "ok" in the console:

```
fetch(".")
.then(function(response) { // first then() call
    return response;
}).then(function(response) { // second then() call
    console.log("ok");
});
```

The page about the [Response Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) of the Fetch API says:

> The fetch() call **returns a promise**, which resolves with the Response
>   object associated with the resource fetch operation.

Well, since `fetch()` returns a Promise object I can understand that the first `then()` call works fine because a Promise object [has this method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). But the Response object returned in the chained call is not a Promise object. However the second call to `then()` method works!

Altering the dummy example prints `undefined` in the first `console.log()`:

```
fetch(".")
.then(function(response) { // first then() call
    console.log(response.then)
    return response;
}).then(function(response) { // second then() call
    console.log("ok");
});
```

My questions is: Why this works? How the second call to `then()` works since the returned object does not have this method? Is it a kind of syntax sugar?

Thanks!

Comment: *"How the second call to then() works since the returned object does not have this method?"* - The `.then()` function calls themselves occur immediately and each return a promise object, they're not dependent on the previous callback in the chain returning something with a `.then()` method.

Comment: To support @nnnnnn, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27716518/4279440 is a good explanation of this behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But the `Response` object returned in the chained call is not a Promise object. However the second call to `then()` method works!

Yes, because the second `.then()` invocation is on the return value of the first `then` call, not on the response. The [promise `then` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) always [returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) - which makes it chainable. It does **not** return the return value of the asynchronous callback - for that it would need to peek into the future.

Look closely:

```
const promise1 = fetch(".");
const promise2 = promise1.then(function(response) { // first then() call
    return response;
});
const promise3 = promise2.then(function(response) { // second then() call
    console.log("ok");
});
```

It's not

```
fetch(".").then(function(response) { // outer then() call
    return response.then(function() { // inner then() call
        console.log("ok");
    });
});
```

which indeed doesn't work without `response` being a promise.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks! :)