# Full Javascript Promise error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

With some research and some of your help I was able to create and comment some code I believe will help people understand Javascript Promises more clearly.

My question is, when I try to trigger a catch by intentionally misspelling the JSON file name, nothing happens. No error. No continue. Nothing. Why?

Why doesn't...

```
else reject( new Error( 'We could not load the URI: ' + uri ) );
```

...gets thrown?

URL for you to visualize without cross origin issues when getting JSON file.

[Test Page](http://nexlevel.org/nextime/)

Content of 
[resultset.json](http://nexlevel.org/nextime/resultset.json)

```
[
  {
    "PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID": 120,
    "CLIENT_ID": 111,
    "PROJECT_ID": 222,
    "USER_ID": 465605,
    "UTL_DTSTAMP": "2018-01-15 17:56:06",
    "UTL_LATITUDE": "40.61105890",
    "UTL_LONGITUDE": "-111.89993530",
    "UTL_EVENT": "CLOCK IN",
    "UTL_ACTION": "MEETING",
    "UTL_DURATION": 3
  },
  {
    "PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID": 122,
    "CLIENT_ID": 111,
    "PROJECT_ID": 222,
    "USER_ID": 465605,
    "UTL_DTSTAMP": "2018-01-15 17:56:19",
    "UTL_LATITUDE": "40.61105890",
    "UTL_LONGITUDE": "-111.89993530",
    "UTL_EVENT": "CLOCK IN",
    "UTL_ACTION": "TRAVEL",
    "UTL_DURATION": 5
  },
  {
    "PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID": 123,
    "CLIENT_ID": 111,
    "PROJECT_ID": 222,
    "USER_ID": 465605,
    "UTL_DTSTAMP": "2018-01-15 17:56:24",
    "UTL_LATITUDE": "40.61105890",
    "UTL_LONGITUDE": "-111.89993530",
    "UTL_EVENT": "CLOCK IN",
    "UTL_ACTION": "TEAR OUT",
    "UTL_DURATION": 3
  }
]
```

**Javascript Promise Code Updated 1/18/2018**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

console.log('1. Document is ready.');

// Run the App.
runApplication();
});

// anything we would like to run *** BEFORE *** getURI( obj ) function is called.
var runFirst = function runFirst() {

console.log( '2. Promise > runFirst() function called.' );
};


// We create a variable called getURI and assign it a function getURI( uri )
var getURI = function getURI( uri ) {

console.log('3. Promise > getURI( uri ) function called.');

// We then create a new Promise (Which is a wrapper..) to return.
return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {

// Our JSON request..
$.getJSON( uri, function( data ) {

// if data is not defined OR an empty string...
if (data =! true || data.length < 1) {

// Create a new error and...
var error = new Error();

// Inject an error status code of 204.
error.status = 204;

// Reject Promise with custom error.
reject( error );

} else {

// Continue...
resolve( data );
}

}).fail( reject );
// Invoke Promise Reject so we can handle the Ajax .fail() by status code.

}); // End promise.
};


// obj edit In Progress.
var processData = function processData( obj ) {

console.log( '3.2 Promise > processData( obj ) function called.' );

// Parse array of arrays if we have to. (For resultSet containing more than one record..)
$.each(obj, function( i, row ) {

// DO...

// Get current row.USER_ID from current row.
console.log('3.2.1 Get: row.USER_ID = '+ row.USER_ID);

// AND OR..
// Set current row.USER_ID to something else..
row.USER_ID = 'something else..';

// AND OR..
// Push a new_element into current row..
row.new_element = 'something new!';

//THEN...

// Get updated row.USER_ID from current row.
console.log('3.2.2 Set: '+ row.USER_ID);

}); // End jQuery for each loop

// Return Original and/or Augmented fectched object.
return Promise.resolve(obj);
};


// obj Done editing. Now we render it. (Display the most up to date version of it.)
var renderData = function renderData( obj ) {

console.log( '3.3 Promise > renderData( obj ) function called.' );
//console.log( obj );

// Return fectched object after being proccessed by processData.
return Promise.resolve(obj);
};


// anything we would like to run *** AFTER *** our getURI( uri ) function is called.
var runLast = function runLast( obj ) {

console.log( '3.4 Promise > runLast() function called.' );
console.log( '3.5 Promise > Successful $.getJSON() response received.' );

// Return fectched object after being proccessed by renderData.
return Promise.resolve(obj);
};

// error handling for $.getJSON() and anything else.
var handleError = function handleError( error ) {

console.log( 'Error - Promise > handleError( error ) function called.' );
console.log( 'Error - We found an error while fetching and/or augmenting some data.' );

// Error if $.getJSON() is status: 204 No Content.
if (error.status == 204) {

console.error( '$.getJSON() .status: ' + error.status + ' - No Content.');
return;
}

// Error if $.getJSON() is status: 404 Not Found.
if (error.status == 404) {

console.error( '$.getJSON() .status: ' + error.status + ' - Not Found.');
return;
}

// Error unknown...
console.log(error);

};


// We create a variable called runApplication and assign it a function runApplication()
var runApplication = function runApplication() {

console.log( '1.1 runApplication() function called.' );

// Similar to Ajax beforeSend()..
runFirst();

// getURI request execution order...
getURI( 'resultset.json' ) // entering Promise...
.then( processData )      // process the data...
.then( renderData )       // render the processed data...
.then( runLast )          // finalize...
.catch( handleError );    // catch our Ajax and Custom errors.)
};
```

Comment: It is an array of arrays.

Comment: It's an Array of Objects, but `row` would still be one of those Objects, so I removed my comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ok. Can you post an update example of my code with where I need to throw it? I must be placing it wrong. I was under the impression the error gets thrown when the promise rejects. The promise reject then triggers a catch which then uses errorHandle to ideally handle the error. This is not happening.

Comment: you can try console.log("something") in else block to debug. I think jQuery silently ignore if json string has error syntax.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: The function that is the second argument to `.getJSON` doesn't execute at all if there is no success. That's like the `success` function.

Comment: Ok. What is the syntax error in my JSON that causes it to fail silently? It is generated by PHP's json_econde. The link to it is in the question

Comment: Also, $.get returns silent too.

Comment: When you change the URL to one that is not `success`ful then both resolve and reject don't fire, since you wrapped them within your `success` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want catch ajax error, add method `.fail` after. As [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) says, `$.getJSON` has silent errors..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log('1. Document is ready.');
});
// We create a variable called getURI and assign it a function getURI( uri )
var getURI = function getURI( uri ) {
    // We then create a new Promise (Which is wrapper..) to return.
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
        // Asynch request for JSON data... (Because that's what we are getting from the server.)
        // ajax commented due to snippet
        $.getJSON( uri, function( data ) {
            // if we got something, resolve promise
            if ( data ) resolve( data );
            // else reject promise and throw an Error.
            else reject( new Error( 'We could not load the URI: ' + uri ) );
        }).fail(reject)
        // End get.
    }); // End promise.
};
// anything we would like to run *** BEFORE *** getURI( obj ) function is called.
var runFirst = function runFirst() {
    console.log( '3.1 Promise > runFirst() function called.' );
};
// obj being edited. Status in progress.
var processData = function processData( obj ) {
    console.log( '3.2 Promise > processData( obj ) function called.' );
        // Parse array of arrays if we have to. (For resultSet containing more than one record..)
        $.each(obj, function( row_idx, row ) {
            // DO...
            // Get current row.USER_ID from current row.
            console.log('3.2.1 Get: '+ row.USER_ID);
            // AND OR..
            // Set current row.USER_ID to something else..
            row.USER_ID = 'something else..';
            // AND OR..
            // Push new row.new_element to something new!
            row.new_element = 'something new!';
            //THEN..
            // Get updated row.USER_ID from current row.
            console.log('3.2.2 Set: '+ row.USER_ID);
        }); // END jQuery for each loop
        // Return Formated Object.
        return Promise.resolve(obj);
};
// obj Done editing. Now we render it. (Display the most up to date version of it.)
var renderData = function renderData( obj ) {
    console.log( '3.3 Promise > renderData( obj ) function called.' );
    //console.log( obj );
    return Promise.resolve(obj);
};
// anything we would like to run *** AFTER *** our getURI( uri ) function is called.
var runLast = function runLast(obj) {
    console.log( '3.4 Promise > runLast() function called.' );
    return Promise.resolve(obj);
};
// finally handleError( error ); how we handle our catch function.
var handleError = function handleError( error ) {
    console.log( '3.x Promise > handleError( error ) function called.' );
    console.log( '3.x We found an error while fetching and augmenting some data.' );
    console.error( error );
};
// We create a variable called runApplication and assign it a function runApplication()
var runApplication = function runApplication() {
    // Similar to Ajax beforeSend()..
    runFirst();
    // getURI request execution order...
    getURI( 'resultset.json' )
        .then( processData )
        .then( renderData )
        .then( runLast )
        .catch( handleError );
};
// I think you can guess what this does.
runApplication();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok. What is the syntax error in my JSON that causes it to fail silently? It is generated by PHP's json_econde.

Comment: Also, $.get returns silent too.

Comment: The json I have is an array of objects. But this causes a syntax error?

Comment: You were talking about misspeled filename of json, it leads probably to 404. And this error is catched by fail method. Your page load json with status code 200 so..

Comment: I've noticed you added return Promise.resolve(obj); instead of return obj. Why? (other than the obvious..)

Comment: In this case, it is same. [You can find detailed answers to your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715275/whats-the-difference-between-returning-value-or-promise-resolve-from-then)

Comment: @Vini btw if you want wrap async func into promise, this is ecma6 shorthand: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => $.getJSON(uri, resolve).fail(reject))`

Comment: I have updated the code to reflect 204 & 404 error handling. Hopefully this will do.