# Difference between Promise returns

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Consider these two functions:

```
function a(){
  //...
  if(something) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  } else {
    return Promise.reject();
  }
}  

function b(){
  //...
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(something) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
}
```

I met more often with second approach, but first one looks a bit cleaner for me. Are there any specific, rare use cases when code would work different with each approach, or is it just semantics?

Comment: If you don't have logic inside `new Promise(` which can throw, and it's only `if` inside, then both versions are equivalent.

Comment: completely the same

Comment: @dfsq, I am not sure but does first function creating Two objects but later one creates only one . So second function is saving memory. Please clear it. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between returning value or Promise.resolve from then()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715275/whats-the-difference-between-returning-value-or-promise-resolve-from-then#27716518)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both examples are pointless because code is synchronous.

If you have a traditional callback function such as `setTimeout` you have to use `new Promise` to convert it to a promise (you cannot return `Promise.resolve(value)` from a callback:

```
const later = (howLong, value) =>
  new Promise(
    resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(value);
        resolve(value)
      }, howLong)
  );
```

Using `Promise.resolve` can be used as an initial value for example when you reduce values asynchronously:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(
  (all, item) =>
    all.then(
      () => later(2000, item)
    ),
  Promise.resolve()//initial value of all
)
```

Another common use case is if your function has to return a promise but can return a value immediately. Let's say you fetch some data and cache it when you got it. The next time you call the function you want it to return a promise because the caller is expecting a promise. You wrap the cached value in a promise:

```
const getData = (
  cache => () =>
    (cache)
      ? Promise.resolve(cache)
      : fetch("someURL").then(r=>r.json()).then(result=>{
        cache=result;
        return result;
      })
)(false)
```

Comment: Another common example for `Promise.resolve`: a function which may return cached data or retrieve data asynchronously, but which should obviously keep one uniform interface would return the cached data using `return Promise.resolve(data)` in order to always return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference that I can see is that function b() returns the **whole promise and can take the accept and reject function from the **parameters of b function. Whereas, the function a() is a predefined Promise, which could have been passed into a() but all the same it's accept and reject are set in stone and returns those functions instead of the Promise Object.