# Node.js Promise with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I have difficulty using Promise.  
I want to get data from one more tables in mongodb. 
but I fell in callback hell, So I tried to solve this but I couldn't. 
What should I do? the result came out 'undefined'.

Many Thanks,

```
let mongoose         = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise     = global.Promise;

....

exports.Recommend = (id) => {
    User.find({User_id: myId})
        .then((result) => {
            return Promise.resolve(result[0].age)
        }).then(age => {
        return new Promise((resolve,rejject)=>{
            resolve(User.find()
                .select('User_id')
                .where('age').equals(age))
            })
        }).then((Users_id) => {
            Users_id.forEach((user, idx, arr) => {
                Count.find()
                 .select('board_id')
                 .where('User_id').equals(user.User_id)
                 .exec((err, items) => {
                     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                         resolve(
                             items.forEach((post, idx, arr) => {
                             posts.push(post.board_id)
                         }))
                     })
                })
        })
    }).then(()=>{
        console.log("posts:"+posts);
    })
}
```

Comment: Don't be creating new promises in `then`! Mongoose will return promises! Just do `return User.find()…`!

Comment: Like this?  " return result[0].age "

Comment: Yes. `Promise.resolve` creates an immediately resolved promise...

Answer (score 1):

[Avoid `Promise.resolve`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27715275/1048572), avoid using the `new Promise` constructor like `Promise.resolve`, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), and [avoid `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572), and don't forget to `return` the promise chain from your function:

```
exports.Recommend = (id) => {
    return User.find({User_id: myId}).then(result => {
        return User.find()
            .select('User_id')
            .where('age')
            .equals(result[0].age));
    }).then(user_ids => {
        return Promise.all(user_ids.map((user, idx, arr) => {
            return Count.find()
                 .select('board_id')
                 .where('User_id').equals(user.User_id)
                 .exec()
                 .then(posts => posts.map(post => post.board_id));
        }));
    }).then(board_ids => {
        console.log("posts:"+board_ids);
    })
}
```

Comment: This is (obviously) the correct idea but the Mongo query itself is wrong - this is a pretty slow way to find all the posts of users of the same age. See [`.populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem with 3rd `.then`, I would like to recommend you to use `Promise.all` function to run the parallel database query. Following example may help you

```
exports.Recommend = (id) => {
    User.find({
            User_id: myId
        })
        .then((result) => {
            return User.find()
                .select('User_id')
                .where('age').equals(result[0].age)
        }).then((Users_id) => {
            return Promise.all(Users_id.map((user, idx, arr) => {
                return Count.find()
                    .select('board_id')
                    .where('User_id').equals(user.User_id)
            }));
        }).then((Users_id) => {
            Users_id.forEach(items => {
                items.forEach(post => {
                    posts.push(post.board_id)
                })
            })
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("posts:" + posts);
        })
}
```