# Typescript pattern - dealing with awaits that can be return void or empty

Tags: typescript, axios, es6-promise

I'm curious if there is a tidy pattern approach I can use for this common scenario:

I have a function that gets a price from making an api call:

```
let currentPrice = await getCurrentPrice(prodId)
```

This `getCurrentPrice()` function in the ideal case makes the api call as usual and returns a string. `Promise<string>`.

```
async function getCurrentPrice(pId: string): Promise<string> {
    axios({ .... })
    .then(res => return res.data.price)
    .catch(err => return "")
}
```

But in the error case I then need to write more logic at the point I made the call like `if currentPrice === ""`.

This doesn't seem very tidy (mostly returning empty strings) hence wondering if there is a clearer pattern better used.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you returning an empty string to begin with? If you remove the `.catch()` block from `getCurrentPrice`, you can handle the error at the call site instead: `try { let currentPrice = await getCurrentPrice(prodId); } catch (error) { /** TODO: Handle error */ }`
If you still need to do some error handling in `getCurrentPrice`, you can catch and then rethrow/throw another error.

Comment: Thats sound something I should do. It guess it also means I need to declare the `let currentPrice = ""` outside the try/catch block. Any other suggestions to that?

Comment: Infact the declaration outside is a little confusing. As the axios response could potentially be undefined its making me declare the response type as `Promise<string | void>`. So do I therefore decalre as just `let currentPrice`

Comment: The code snippet you have provided doesn't return the promise, which means your function doesn't return anything... that looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Should it be `return Promise.resolve(res.data.price)` ? I thought as I have the await thats like the `then` https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168159/3033691

Comment: No, it should just be `return axios({...})...`

Comment: *or* you could use `async/await` with `axios` instead of `.then` and await it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242265/discussion-between-usermod2-and-ben-wainwright).