# promise with finally block

Tags: node.js, promise

Anyone master with Promises? I believe there's something subtle here and someone with deep knowledge has an idea.

I'm using the finally block with the promise for the first time. The issue is, can you return a value from then or catch handlers into the finally handler after a promise has been settled (resolved/rejected)?

Consider the following example in the context of pooled connections in MySQL.

```
let sql = "SELECT id, first, last FROM employee";
let values = [];

this.pool.getConnection()
    .then(connection => {
        return this.pool.query(connection, sql, values);
    })
    .then(({connection, result}) => {
        resolve({code: 200, result: result});
        return connection; // connection is defined here
    })
    .catch(({connection, error}) => {
        reject({code: 400, result: error.sqlMessage});
        return connection; // connection is defined here
    })
    .finally(connection => {
        console.log(connection); // undefined
        if (connection) this.pool.release(connection);
    });
```

**Issue**: I'm getting connection as undefined in the finally block.

Comment: finally doesn't receive an argument.  Place the connection in the enclosing scope.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally

Comment: Have to pick either return or resolve, can't do both at once. So, moving connection out with the other vars as danh suggested would help fix that issue too. Relevant [Q with a few good A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715275/whats-the-difference-between-returning-value-or-promise-resolve-from-then).

Comment: @l3l_aze I'm still confused, possible for you to give a code example, will much appreciate.

Comment: I was wrong, [can use return after resolve/reject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536049/do-i-need-to-return-after-early-resolve-reject), otherwise I would try to provide code. Could try to blame it on 4am, but I just suck at Promises. Regarding moving the variable to the outer scope: Declare connection with the other variables and it'll be accessible throughout just like they are. Then if there's any trouble, use `if (typeof connection !== 'undefined')`  in the `finally`, as it won't throw an error if the variable `connection` is undefined.

Comment: A bit of state management if I had to keep the connection out of the pipeline, but I worked out it in another way. I'm releasing the connection before `resolve/reject` but it seems like the `finally` block is useless in the sense that it doesn't receive values from previous `then` or `catch` blocks.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to better learn promises since this, and what helped most is the same article I've been reading for years [by Nolan Lawson](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html), though of course [MDN - Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) is also good. I'm sure this could be done better, but I tried to document it heavily so it's at least helpful.

```js
'use strict'

const sql = 'SELECT id, first, last FROM employee'
const values = []

// Unfriendly weakly-mocked mysqljs to allow forcing success/failure for tests.
const mysql = (function() {
  const _pool = {}

  return {
    pool: {
      getConnection: function(succeeds) {
        if (succeeds) {
          const id = Date.now()
          _pool[id] = id
          console.log('Pool: ', _pool)
          return Promise.resolve(`${id}`)
        } else {
          return Promise.reject(new Error('Failed to get connection from pool'))
        }
      },

      query: function(connection, sql, values, succeeds) {
        if (succeeds) {
          return Promise.resolve('Succeeded')
        } else {
          return Promise.reject(new Error('Query failed'))
        }
      },

      // More like connection.destroy, but easier to test.
      release: function(cid) {
        if (typeof _pool[cid] === 'undefined') {
          throw new Error('Attempting to release invalid connection.')
        } else {
          delete _pool[cid]
          return undefined
        }
      }
    }
  }
})();

// Wrapped in async so it's possible to use await and
//   test all 3 possibilities sequentially. Also
//   avoids the need for a more realistic pool.
(async function() {
  // Flags for forced success or failure
  const willSucceed = true
  const willFail = false

  /*
   *
   * Query success example
   *
   */
  await mysql.pool.getConnection(willSucceed)
    .then(connection => {
      return mysql.pool.query(connection, sql, values, willSucceed)
        .then(result => {
          console.log('Succeeded')
          return Promise.resolve(result)
        })
        .finally(() => {
          console.log(`Connection (finally): ${connection}`)

          // Used to destroy the value, don't actually set
          //   the value of connection like this.
          connection = mysql.pool.release(connection)

          console.log(`Connection (after): ${connection}`)
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(`${err?.message || 'Failed.'}.`)
    })

  /*
   *
   * Query failure example
   *
   */
  await mysql.pool.getConnection(willSucceed)
    .then(connection => {
      // Scope with "connection" starts
      return mysql.pool.query(connection, sql, values, willFail)
        .then(result => {
          console.log('This will never succeed')
          return Promise.resolve('Not happening')
        })
        .finally(() => {
          // But this runs whether or not the query fails
          console.log(`Connection (finally): ${connection}`)

          // Used to destroy the value, don't actually set
          //   the value of connection like this.
          connection = mysql.pool.release(connection)

          console.log(`Connection (after): ${connection}`)
        })

      // Scope with "connection" ends
    })
    // This will catch failure to connect or a query failure,
    // but a catch can be added before finally if you want to
    //   catch query failure in particular.
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(`${err?.message || 'Failed.'}.`)
    })

  /*
   *
   * Connection failure example
   *
   */
  await mysql.pool.getConnection(willFail)
    .then(connection => {
      console.log('This will never succeed, so was gutted')
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Panic!'))
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(`${err?.message || 'Failed.'}.`)
    })
})()
```